# How to make an application that gather some app that already in our device.

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to to make an application that gather some app that already in our device. Like an iBook but, this store App instead of books.

I'm not sure where I should take a look at ? Intent or BroadcastReceiver? If you have any suggestions,or any relate-field of example, it would be nice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will show you what's on your device:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
    "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
List<ResolveInfo> rilist = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo ri : rilist)
{
  Log.i("TAG", "package: " + ri.activityInfo.packageName + ", class: "
      + ri.activityInfo.name);
  AppInfo info = new AppInfo(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
      ri.activityInfo.name, ri.loadIcon(pm));
  appsMap.put(ri.activityInfo.packageName, info);
}
```